# Can i Have two different styles in one UIWebView in IOS 5

Tags: html, css, ios, uiwebview

Here is my code:

```
         CGRect frame9 = CGRectMake(392, 100, 320, 329);

         UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame9];
         [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

         NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"<html>"
                                "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                " body   {background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #c8b981 ; font-size:18px;text-align :justify;} .titulo {background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #42382b ; font-size:11px;}"
                                "</style>"
                                "<body>"
                                "<p class = titulo > %@ </p>"
                                "<p>%@</p>"
                                "<p2 { background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #42382b ; font-size:11px;text-align :left};> %@ </p2>"                                    
                                "<p>%@</p>"
                                "<h2 style =background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #42382b ; font-size:11px;text-align :left;> %@ </h2>"                                    
                                "<p>%@</p>"
                                "</body></html>",@"A LA VISTA", vino.vista,@"POR LA NARIZ" ,vino.nariz,@"AL PALADAR" , vino.paladar];

         [webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];

         webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         [webView setOpaque:NO];
         webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
         [subview addSubview:webView];
```

What i Want to do is to have one Style for the Body and one style for the Titles but is not working..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your HTML needs a bit of work. Try using classes for your p tags. I think this is what you are going for though.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><style type='text/css\'> body { background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #c8b981; font-size:18px;text-align:justify} .class1 { background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #0000FF; font-size:11px; } .class2 { background-color:transparent; font-family:Helvetica; color: #FF0000 ; font-size:11px; }' </style><body> <p class='class1'> Class1 </p><p class='class2'> Class2 </p><p> No Class </p></body></html>";

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Really? I testing in a WebView worked fine for me. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: Used your code and it seems to be ok. Not sure what your going for. Does your webview output this? All you should have to do is change what your NSString *htmlContentString is equal to (my html and your html shown) http://imgur.com/a/OFd4a